# Using different API url for development and production with React and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, create-react-app

I'm building web app with React frontend and Node.js backend (API).
In React frontend I call API methods like this:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://servername:9999/reports.activities',
    data: {
        user_id: 1
    }
}).then(res => {
    this.setState(res.data);
});
```

Sometimes I need to test API methods that is not released to production yet.
When I test backend locally, i run `nodemon api.js` on `localhost:9999`.
Every time I want to test frontend with local-running API, I have to change `http://servername:9999` to `http://localhost:9999` in my frontend code.
I think this is not the right approach.
What is the best way to use different url for development (when run `npm start` locally) and production (`npm build`)?
I was thinking of using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) for this purpose. Is this the right approach?
What is the best practice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using create-react-app you have already dotenv installed.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

So you can so:

```
const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT || 'http://production';

...
url: `${API_ENDPOINT}/reports.activities`
```

Answer (score 14):

You can create 2 `.env` files called `.env.development` and `.env.production`.

```
//.env.development
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:9999
```

```
//.env.production
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=https://servername:9999
```

Then use it as follows -

```
//api.js
const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${API_ENDPOINT}/reports.activities`,
    data: {
        user_id: 1
    }
}).then(res => {
    this.setState(res.data);
});
```

The way it works is: when you run `npm start`, react will use the `.env.development` file and when you do `npm run build`, react will use the `.env.production` file.

Here's the relevant part of the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used).

Comment: do we need to add the //.env.development and //.env.production in the .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

If you swict to vite you can use. Default vite expose all env variables start withs VITE_

```
import.meta.VITE_SOME
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35083418)