# Domain in checkout view to enable payments in production environment with Stripe and Django

Tags: django, django-views, stripe-payments

I have a question, what domain url I should include in the code below to make payments possible in production environment. When I include link to the development website it works on development server (and does not work on the production server), but when I provide the website address related to the production server it doesn't work. What address local/production I should include to make it work?

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    domain_url = ''

    stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    try:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            client_reference_id=request.user.id if  
request.user.is_authenti$
            success_url=domain_url + '/success?session_id=

{CHECKOUT_SESSION$
            cancel_url=domain_url + '/cancel/',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='subscription',
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price': STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
                    'quantity': 1,
                }
            ]
        )
        return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

Template with the Subscribe button:

```
   `{% load static %}

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-  
   scale=1">
     <title>Django + Stripe Subscriptions</title>
     <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
      
    <script src="{% static 'static/main.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      {% if subscription.status == "active" %}
        <h4>Your subscription:</h4>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              {{ product.description }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"   
    id="submitBtn">Subscribe</button>
      {% endif %}
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

...

```
   console.log("Sanity check!");

    // Get Stripe publishable key
    fetch("/config/")
    .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
    .then((data) => {
    // Initialize Stripe.js
    const stripe = Stripe(data.publicKey);
 
    // Event handler
    let submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submitBtn");
    if (submitBtn !== null) {
     submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
     // Get Checkout Session ID
     fetch("/create-checkout-session/")
       .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
        .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        // Redirect to Stripe Checkout
        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: data.sessionId})
        })
       .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
       });
      });
     }
    });
```

View stripe_config:

```
   @csrf_exempt
   def stripe_config(request):
       if request.method == 'GET':
          stripe_config = {'publicKey': STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}
          return JsonResponse(stripe_config, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is up to you -- you can include any domain you like in the success and cancel URL. This is where you customer will be redirected to whether they complete (or bail out of) a Checkout session.

If you can provide more details about this remark, then I might be able to offer more specific guidance:

> when I provide the website address related to the production server it doesn't work

What doesn't work?

Comment: When I use development url (http://dev.domainname. com) everything works good. But when I use standard url (http://domainname.com),  I can't display stripe template with credit card payment when I press Subscribe button. It doesn't redirect to the checkout session. I wonder if this might be related to the specific requirements of hosting service.  Or it might be related to the fact that I should use only production stripe keys, not test data  - maybe test data are only compatible with the development server? Is it enough specific? Do you now solution in what way to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean "can't display stripe template with credit card payment when I press Subscribe button" ? If you're using Checkout, this is handled by the hosted Checkout session for you. Are there errors you can share? Network or console errors? Where does this fail, in your server, in your client code, on the Stripe page? Please be specific about what exactly is not working.

Comment: I've edited main post to provide more code to explain in what way Subscribe button works. I wonder if it might be related to the hosting service specific requirements, or maybe I should use not test data from stripe but production API keys. Maybe  this is another reason, but I've just started with Stripe/django integration and don't know.

Comment: Maybe problem is anological to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896204/using-different-api-url-for-development-and-production-with-react-and-axios as I use AJAX and maybe it requires different API url.

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1622817.aspx?+ajax+url+on+dev+and+prod+ I see that url in AJAX should be different in dev and production environment but I do not get the format yet.