# How to avoid a hardcoded IP address in React JS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, hardcoded

I have a React JS/Spring Boot app where the React JS part accesses the Spring Boot server URL via a link to get a report.

The problem is that, first, the IP address is hardcoded in React, and second, I have to swap the IP address to localhost when testing.

Here's the code:

```
  download() {
    // fake server request, getting the file url as response
    setTimeout(() => {
      const response = {
//        file: "http://1.1.1.1:9080/api/export",
        file: "http://localhost:8080/api/export",
      };
      // server sent the url to the file!
      // now, let's download:
      window.open(response.file);
    }, 100);
  }
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Parametrize it server-side before serving the website.

Comment: If using create-react-app, you have dotenv already available. If not: you can install it or using envvars in any case.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896204/using-different-api-url-for-development-and-production-with-react-and-axios/52896282#52896282

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using different API url for development and production with React and axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896204/using-different-api-url-for-development-and-production-with-react-and-axios)

Comment: @keul - if I'm reading the doc correctly, it means I would have to change a .env variable locally before compiling it for production. Is this correct? If so, it still means I'd have to remember to change it and recompile it before uploading it to the prod server, right?

Comment: @Alejandro - how would that work? You mean to create an API on the server that would check the environment and provide the IP address? Or have the server code read a file on the server that would contain the IP address?

Comment: @JackBeNimble I mean, before serving the Javascript/HTML check your configuration (server side) and change the returned Javascript accordingly. The browser won't notice the difference and the server would only serve that content once, at first page load.

Comment: @JackBeNimble you can have separate .env files that are automatically picked up when building for production or for local development. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used